# Which data is original for the "Device's power estimate"?

Tags: android, battery, historian

I've investigating about the data of Device's power estimate in the Battery historian tool. This is my current conclusion for the Device's power estimate percentage. Battery historian reads the Estimated power use(mAh) in order to obtain a Device's power estimate percentage.

Is this conclusion correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. For my application, the Estimated Power use shows as `Uid u0a231: 21.1 ( cpu=21.1 wifi=0.000823 )` and since my CPU capacity is 2300, the expected % is `(21.1/2300 * 100) = 0.917` and the battery historian displays `Device's power estimate` as `0.92%` that matches.